# How to determine expected uptime of an event with a probability of 10%

Tags: probability

So I'm trying to figure out how to model an event in a game with the following "parameters":

- Event lasts 10 seconds
- Probability it will happen is 10%
- the chance to make it happen is rolled every 2 seconds and it can overlap (resulting in "wasted" time)

What I'm trying to determine without using a random number generator is how often it will take 1 roll, or 2 rolls, or 3 rolls, etc. to make it trigger, weighted together to give an average # of hits required while taking into consideration the duration loss from overlapping events.

I've looked into using `1 - (1 - 1/10) ^ n` where n = number of hits but that just gives me the chance it will happen based on the number of hits. If it only takes 4 or less hits, there will be overlap.

I'm assuming 10 hits on average would be expected if I don't care about overlap, but that doesn't account for lost time because of overlapping events. So I'm expecting something closer to 14-15 but not sure how to approach that value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the relevance of the overlapping. If two events overlap, they are still different events, right?

Comment: Overlapping events is considered a refresh, so if you triggered on the first roll you lose 8 seconds of total uptime.

The main thing I'm modeling is uptime of an event, given the chances to trigger and the duration. Say out of 300 seconds, how many seconds will it be active. In order to get to that point, I'm looking for a way to say "an average of x rolls to trigger will give y uptime"

So overlapping triggers will reduce the uptime. If it always takes at least 10 seconds before a trigger, the uptime will be higher because there is no refreshes.